# Appending from specific line onward to new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to append from a certain line onward from a url link, the link is a .txt file that contain something similar to the following:
X -- Y -- Z
3 -- 5 -- 1
6 -- 4 -- 2
7 -- 2 -- 3
and so forth....
I only managed to have it read all the file and appending them to a new one, but I want to omit the first line.

```
import urllib.request as ur
import shutil
with ur.urlopen(#link) as link, open("#filePath", 'ab') as Data:
        shutil.copyfileobj(link, Data)
```

Is there a way to slice the lines within the url to append to the new file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip the first line explicitly:

```
import urllib.request as ur
import shutil
with ur.urlopen(#link) as link, open("#filePath", 'ab') as Data:
    link.readline()  # Reads one line, discards it, leaves link positioned after it
                     # next(link, None) should also work; there are subtle differences,
                     # but either should work here
    shutil.copyfileobj(link, Data)
```